# Haskell List Comprehension - Ineffective Predicate

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I'm pretty brand new to Haskell (only written a fizzbuzz program before the current one) and am trying to write a program that takes the unix wordlist ('/usr/share/dict/words') and prints out the list of anagrams for that word, with any direct palindromes starred. I have the meat of this summed up into one function:

```
findAnagrams :: [String] -> [(String, [String])]
findAnagrams d =
  [x | x <- map (\s -> (s, [if reverse s == t then t ++ "*" else t | t <- d, s /= t && null (t \\ s)])) d, not (null (snd x))]
```

However, when I run the program I get this output:

```
abase: babes, bases
abased: debase
abasement: basements
abasements: abatements
abases: basses
```

And so on, so clearly it isn't working properly. My intention is for the list comprehension to read as follows: for all t in d such that t is not equal to s and there is no difference between t and s other than order, if t is the reverse of s include as t*, otherwise include as t. The problem seems to be with the "no difference between t and s other than order" part, which I'm trying to accomplish by using "null (t \ s)". It seems like it should work. Testing in GHCI gives:

```
Prelude Data.List> null ("abatements" \\ "abasements")
False
```

And yet it passes the predicate test. My assumption is that I'm missing something simple here, but I've looked at it a while and can't quite come up with it.

In addition, any notes regarding best practice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I ran your code and it didn't give me those anagrams.  Check again.  Regarding style, the line is very long.  Consider pulling some things out into their own functions.

Comment: It looks like your major problem is in how you're checking for anagrams.  Instead of doing a list difference, what other kinds of tests could you do to check if both words have the same letters?  Does order really matter, or could you change the order of the letters before comparing?

Comment: @TomEllis the code works great (well, maybe ok) if `d` contains more than one string, especially anagrams! Try `findAnagrams ["bac", "abc", "cab"]`

Comment: @groovy: Indeed the code works better than Dr Eigenvalue seems to think, but bheklilr's still right: the code is not correct.

Comment: As people here have implied, this isn't a case where a list comprehension is particularly useful or idiomatic.  Consider breaking it out into normal functions, using `map` and `filter`.

Answer (score 1):

If you break it out into multiple functions (remember, source code size is not really that important), you could do something like:

```
import Data.List

isPalindrome :: String -> Bool
isPalindrome s = s == reverse s

flagPalins :: [String] -> [String]
flagPalins [] = []
flagPalins (x:xs)
    | isPalindrome x = x ++ "*"
    | otherwise      = x

isAnagram :: String -> String -> Bool
isAnagram s t = (isPalindrome s || s /= t) && ??? -- test for anagram

findAnagrams :: String -> [String] -> [String]
findAnagrams s ws = flagPalins $ filter (isAnagram s) ws

findAllAnagrams :: [String] -> [(String, [String])]
findAllAnagrams ws = filter (not . null . snd) ??? -- words paired with their anagrams
```

I've intentionally left some holes for you to fill in, I'm not going to give you all the answers ;)

There are only two spots for you to do yourself.  The one in `findAllAnagrams` should be pretty easy to figure out, you're already doing something pretty similar with your `map (\s -> ...)` part.  I intentionally structured `isAnagram` so it'll return `True` if it's a palindrome or if it's just an anagram, and you only need one more check to determine if `t` is an anagram of `s`.  Look at the comment I made on your question for a hint about what to do there.  If you get stuck, comment and ask for an additional hint, I'll give you the name of the function I think you should use to solve this problem.

---

If you really want to make a list comprehension, I would recommend solving it this way, then converting back to a comprehension.  In general you should write more verbose code, then compress it once you understand it fully.

Answer (score 1):

Think of `a \\ b` as "items in `a` that are not in `b`."

Consider the implications.